# Rsuite SelectPicker need to get the value of label

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, rsuite

Need to get the value of label in the select picker

drop_down_data has these two values

value:(here is the id or key)
label:(is the name)

sample data:
value:"60868932d8c9e10c42a93df0",
label:"Tony Stark"

This is my code:

```
                  <Field
                    name="first_group_name"
                    render={(fieldProps) => (
                      <SelectPicker
                        data={this.props.drop_down_data}
                        // searchable={false}
                        size="lg"
                        onChange={fieldProps.input.onChange}
                        value={fieldProps.input.value}
                        placeholder="Group name"
                      />
                    )}
                  />
```

when console logging fieldProps the only thing that gets passed down is the value.
how can I get label?